# Can't get connections from a ConnectionPool on Heroku with Jetty/JSP

Tags: jsp, postgresql, heroku, connection, jetty

I've tried to use a connection pool with Jetty on Heroku.  I am coming up with some problems.  Mainly here is the error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /displayUsers. Reason:
    Server Error
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.data.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:48)
    at com.data.UserPassDB.getUsers(UserPassDB.java:15)
    at com.example.DisplayUsersServlet.doGet(DisplayUsersServlet.java:21)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820**)
```

---

Here is my code for the webapp/META-INF/context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myAppName" docBase="myAppName"
   crossContext="true" reloadable="true" debug="1">


    <Resource name="RESOURCE/NAME" auth="Container"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="username" password="password"
        driverClassName="com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=true"
        logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

This is the code for my servlet that will access the database & attempt to show the users in the database:

```
package com.data;

/**PURPOSE:  This starts the db ConnectionPool. 
 * You can connect to this ConnectionPool object to obtain one Connection out of the pool at any time. 
 * Once done, you can release the Connection object back to the ConnectionPool. 
 * 
 */
import java.sql.*;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class ConnectionPool
{
    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    private ConnectionPool()
    {
        try
        {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            Context envContext  = (Context)ic.lookup("java:/comp/env");

            dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("RESOURCE/NAME");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static ConnectionPool getInstance()
    {
        if (pool == null)
        {
            pool = new ConnectionPool();
        }
        return pool;
    }

    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void freeConnection(Connection c)
    {
        try
        {
            c.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code that is using that ConnectionPool class above to connect..

```
package com.data;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.model.UserPass;

public class UserPassDB {
    public static ArrayList<UserPass> getUsers()
    {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        String query = "select * from user";
        ArrayList<UserPass> userAry = new ArrayList<UserPass>();
        try{
            Statement stmnt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                UserPass user = new UserPass();
                user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                userAry.add(user);
            }

        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userAry;
    }
}
```

My ConnectionPool w/ Jetty in my JSP application is failing on Heroku and I'm not sure why.. I do have that useSSL paramenter on the end of the URL for the ConnectionPool in the context.xml file. 
I don't know what's wrong.. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Don't write your own connection pool. They're hard to get right. There are several existing quality implementations; use one.

Comment: Oh cool. thanks.. I can connect with a regular connection string, but I think a Connection Pool would be faster for my application as well as good for then using Authentication in my code and also specify which files those authenticated people can go to?  If you are talking about just a regular DB Connection, I have already done that..  Is that what you meant by a quality implementation? Or are there other ways to make a connection pool "happen"  Sorry..I"m sort of a newbie to Connection Pools.. :)  Thanks again for your response. :)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question, fixing title. You seem to have left out the most important class, `com.data.ConnectionPool`. Show that code.

Comment: Oh, nice catch.. Sorry about that. I've update the code. It's the 3rd code text box.  :)  Thanks again. :)

Comment: OK, so you can see what line 48 is, right? Therefore, `dataSource` must be null there. You fail to test to see whether it's non-null when you request it in the `ConnectionPool()` ctor, where it's set by `(DataSource)envContext.lookup("RESOURCE/NAME");`. So start by looking into that. On a side note, your code is subject to race conditions that can create multiple pools if more than one thread requests an instance at a time during startup. (I don't understand why you're doing all this the way you are, when there are well established, documented methods for using connection pools in Jetty...)